# must be instance django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, valueerror

This is the merchant model:

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
     merchant_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

and this is transaction model which the first field is linked to merchant_token on Merchant model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
     transaction_merchant_token = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

First I get the merchant token with POST request then I get the merchant field with:

```
merchant = Merchant.objects.get(merchant_token__exact=posted_token)
```

but when I want to insert new transaction with posted token:

```
new_transaction = Transaction(
                                transaction_merchant_token=merchant.merchant_token
                            )
                            new_transaction.save()
```

I get ValueError exception:

> Cannot assign "93C38:9VLlOUuaRq7J8boHyX80cI5MYy8yCpsb": Transaction.transaction_merchant_token must be a Merchant instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the merchant instance itself not the token

```
new_transaction = Transaction(transaction_merchant_token=merchant)
new_transaction.save()
```

I would redefine the models to look like this

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
     token = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Transaction(models.Model):
     merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then when you want to get the merchant token, you do it this way

```
new_transaction.merchant.token
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually a `ForeignKey` refers to a *model object*, not to the primary key of that object.

Yes, Django will make a `field_id` (given the name of the `ForeignKey` field is `field`) to store the value of the primary key of the referred model object, and only the `field_id` is a realy database column. But the `field_id`, is *not* the same as a `field`.

You can thus do two things:

1. you use the `transaction_merchant_token` field, and you pass a `Merchant` object:

   ```
   new_transaction = Transaction(
       transaction_merchant_token=merchant
   )
   ```
2. you use the `transaction_merchant_token_id` field, and then you pass the value of the primary key (for example the token):

   ```
   new_transaction = Transaction(
       transaction_merchant_token_id=merchant.pk
   )
   ```

> **Note** (*nomenclature*): that since the `ForeignKey` is thus not the token itself, it is common to name the `ForeignKey` after the model,
>   not after the primary key of the model object, so I advise to rename
>   your foreign key, for example to:
>
> ```
> class Transaction(models.Model):
>      transaction_merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
> ```
>
> or even better:
>
> ```
> class Transaction(models.Model):
>      merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
> ```
>
> prefixing the attributes with the name of the current model is not
>   necessary, and might be bad if you want to use "*duck typing*" in
>   functions.

Comment: This couldn't have been explained better! I would just like to add that if he is going to go with the second suggestion, he has to update the `merchant_token` field by replacing `unique=True` with `primary_key=True`.

Comment: @NourChawich: aarrghhh... yes, I somehow misread it, thanks for the head's up.